# how to change current displaying uiview without using segues?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, loadview

[image]i want to change display to an UIViewController which has view controller at storyboard from an UIViewController class which hasn't got view controller at storyboard. There is no segue at storyboard for this...

Comment: self.navigationController coming null, my sourceUIViewController class have no navigationController and no connection with storyboard. i'm looking for an other solution way??

Comment: in my opinion my problem is associated with this warning "Warning: Attempt to present <MapViewController: 0x80d0bc0> on <EventCoordinates: 0x80cfde0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" so how can i show a UIViewController view from a class which is not in the window hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

In your AppDelegate.m do a quick setup:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    ViewController *sourceViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sourceViewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController:nav];
    return YES;
}
```

In above example replace `ViewController` class with your own class of `sourceViewCntroller`

```
- (IBAction) didPressMyButton {
    NewViewController* newVC = [[[NewViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
}
```

Connect this action to a button on storyboard or embed view change in any method. You will need to setup UINavigation controller first.

Comment: but this must work in -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {}

Comment: -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection { 
  [self didPressMyButton];
}

Comment: there is no interface of this class at storyboard. isn't it a problem for button action?

Comment: You can embed this code in any function you want. There is no problem having action not connected to storyboard element. You may move those two lines to your function that finishes downloading page, you can make a function like -(void) goToNextViewController. You are free to use this code anywhere in your class.

Comment: self.navigationController coming null, my sourceUIViewController class have no navigationController. i'm looking for an other solution way??

Comment: Do a quick setup as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but I think you are asking how to load a view controller from a storyboard, without using a segue, from a method in a view controller that wasn't loaded from the storyboard.

First, in your storyboard, select the view controller you want to load, and open the Identity Inspector.  Set the Storyboard ID of the view controller.  It looks like you want to load a `MapViewController`, so let's say you set the storyboard ID to `map`.

In your code, you can load the view controller like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MapViewController *mapViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"map"];
```

Once you have a reference to the view controller, you can set its properties or send it messages. You can then display it in whatever way you want - maybe by pushing it onto a navigation controller, or by presenting it, or by setting it as the root view controller of your window.

Comment: i think my problem is associated with warning "Warning: Attempt to present <MapViewController: 0x80d0bc0> on <EventCoordinates: 0x80cfde0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" so how can i show a UIViewController view from a class which is not in the window hierarchy?